# Expert pop up Window on SU is Eliza - Can we kill it!

Tags: discussion

First off, this has NOT been answered any where. My question is not "is this new?" or "what is this about?". My post is, can we destroy it?

[image]

What a load of nonsense. SU is full of experts willing to give their time. Each answer is bespoke and for the most part, not only useful but in many cases many different resolutions are offered. This pop up, which was clearly a robot, can only harm and degrade SU with it's useless, pre-programmed text and suggestions (which by the way popped up before I logged in, meaning this could be the first impression to a new visitor).

I suggest it is removed and killed with fire.

Reference to [Eliza](http://nlp-addiction.com/eliza/)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vMeTe.png

Comment: Yeah, I've seen similar posts asking about it, mine is suggesting we kill it. The SU site is professional; this is not! There is a reason the paperclip animation/helper is no longer shipped with MS products! Please remove the banner saying it's been asked else where, the 2 questions are very different!

Comment: considering the day it is today...

Comment: oh crumbs... d'oh!! D'oh d'oh d'oh! Well, excellent! I will go and hang my head in shame!

Comment: The thing is it's popping up way to often.

Comment: Too often? Aww, sounds like fun, but I didn't get to see this in action even once, don't know why. :( Maybe the fact that I was browsing on a tablet with a crappy Chrome browser prevented it from being displayed... If that's the case, something for the devs to fine tune next time.

Comment: @Karan - I was getting this 5 minutes yesterday. It continued even after I hit `Never` which is interesting.  Of course yesterday was April 1st so perhaps Clippy and the Wizard was playing a joke and all of us?

Comment: @Ramhound: "... so perhaps Clippy and the Wizard was playing a joke and all of us" - I think we all know that's the case by now. :) I can see how too much of a good thing would really begin to jar though.

Comment: @Ramhound Perhaps you clear your cookies too often?  Just a thought...

Comment: @Seth...  really....  come on.  I think Ramhound knows about cookies!!!   :-)

Comment: @Seth - I use the same instance of IE in a single 8 hour shift.

Comment: I think having this joke is fine but should only have been shown to registered users. April fool doesn't work if it's not out of context and first time visitors will not appreciate the context of SU